# how can i create a team project in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs

i want to learn step by step in build a team project in tfs 2010

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy:

1. Run VS 2010 as Administrator
2. Open Team Explorer
3. Right click on the project collection you want
4. Select "New Team Project"
5. Select process template and other settings
6. Proceed to end.

Comment: how can i create a server for tfs 2010?

Comment: @mohammad: do you mean a TFS Project Collection or a really TFS Server?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [turorial](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bmains/archive/2010/05/01/setting-up-a-team-foundation-server-2010-project.aspx) to get you started.  It should have everything you are looking for.

Comment: thanks it's work. now I can't create server for tfs 2010.please help me Robert

Answer (score 1):

In VisualStudio 2012:

1. Open Team Explorer
2. Click tab 'Home'
3. Click dropdown 'Home|Current_team_project_name' under tabs
4. Select 'Projects and My Teams'
5. Select 'New Team Project...'